# c3p0 connection Pooling error - Oracle RAC

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0

On a 2 node cluster when one node is shutdown the following c3p0 errors are seen:

```
2015-11-10 10:00:25,655 | WARN  | scheduler-1          | org.apache.log4j.Category | Exception on close of inner statement.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:5416)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1585)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1570)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:94)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.close(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:82)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.close(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1811)
```

The above warning is followed by :

```
2015-11-10 10:00:25,668 | WARN  | DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10 | org.apache.log4j.Category | [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection ] which will not be reported to listeners!
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:5416)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1585)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1570)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:94)
```

Ase per the comment by Steve Swaldman on [c3p0 github page](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues/6),these warnings are associated with invalid/stale connections.

So on oracle RAC environment when one instance is shutdown , what happens to the connections already acquired when the node was up and running? for most part the Database operations were working fine after node shutdown. Only few inserts failed throwing the Warnings above. Does c3p0 connection pooling suitable for use on RAC environments?

More information about the warnings : http://sourceforge.net/p/c3p0/mailman/message/18310863/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings shown above don't look to be a problem. c3p0 was trying to clean up Statements whose parent Connection was already close()ed.

In general, c3p0 will gracefully recover from database outtages under common configurations. But you may see some warnings and Exceptions as tests start to fail and then attempts to clean things up fail as well.

c3p0 should work fine with Oracle RAC. However, Oracle's [Universal Connection Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/toc.htm) offers [special support for RAC-specific features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/rac.htm#JJUCP08100) that c3p0 does not provide.

Comment: Thanks.Initially when both nodes are up some connections will be acquired. when a node is shutdown , the database operations will be processed by the other instance that is still up and running. So the connections acquired first  before node goes down are still valid? It has been seen that first few records after the node went down are not inserted in the DB.

Comment: no, once a node goes down, Connections to it will be invalid. you should configure Connection testing so that bad Connections are not provided to clients. then only Connections already checked out when the database went down will experience errors. please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing

Comment: Steve,one last thing. If i use connections testing(preferredTestQuery,testConnectionOnCheckout) , will it help to avoid the Warnings seen above which are probably caused during the time interval when a node goes down and those connections acquired using that instance becomes invalid?

Comment: You should be [using some form of Connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing) no matter what, but you still may see those messages. the messages that you are seeing are likely from the Statement cache. (If they were in-use client Connections, you'd see problems at query attempts as well as close()) Even while Connections are not in use, cached PreparedStatements remain open, and c3p0 will try one way or another to close() those Statements when it closes the Connection, even if the server on the other side of them is invalid.

Comment: If you turn Statement caching off (don't set config params `maxStatements` or `maxStatementsPerConnection`) and turn on Connection testing, you'll probably see errors more rarely. But hopefully you are getting a performance boost from Statement caching. (It's only an educated guess on my part that these are likely closes by Statement cache. If you have longer stack traces, they would provide more certainty.)

Comment: Currently in the configuration both maxStatements and maxStatementsPerConnection are set to 0. I just read your previous comment again , "then only Connections already checked out when the database went down will experience errors". Does this mean that even with very good connection testing applications will still used invalid connections and cause errors? In my case i don't want to use a bad connection(acquired before a node went down) which was checked out earlier and close it.

Comment: Basically no insertions(any other operations) should proceed with invalid connections(these should be closed). Is this something that is not internally managed by c3p0? i thought the point of extensive connection testing was to detect invalid connections(node goes down) and not to use these.

Comment: c3p0 will check the validity of Connections while it manages them, either periodically when they are idle (not checked out), or immediately upon checkout, depending on how you choose to [configure Connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing). There is always some possibility that a Connection will be invalidated after checkout and before use, but that should be rare, if, as you should, you keep Connections checked out as briefly as possible.